# Google Contacts Dir in Google Sites

Tags: google-sheets, automation, directory, google-apps, google-sites

I am currently making a Google Site where I would like to embed my contacts. The contacts I am referring to can be found if I log into my gmail account and click on ->Mail->Contacts on the upper left hand corner. Then, on the next page, I click the "Other Contacts" link.

I have tried using a google spreadsheet to read in this data and then displaying that in the Google Site. However, I ran into a few issues. I tried the IMPORTHTML("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts/group/26ae/Other+Contacts","table",1). This didn't return anything. I tried to change the second parameter to 'list' and for the third parameter, I went up to 30 so I doubt that is the issue.

I also tried this approach but no luck. https://www.import.io/post/how-to-get-live-web-data-into-a-spreadsheet-without-ever-leaving-excel/

What would be the best way to resolve this issue of getting those contacts to show up in my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three options:

1. [Export your contacts to a CSV](http://A%20spreadsheet%20ID%20can%20be%20extracted%20from%20its%20URL.%20For%20example,%20the%20spreadsheet%20ID%20in%20the%20URL%20https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0%20is%20%22abc1234567%22.) and import that into a sheet.  The downside is that this is not syncing, it is a static update, so maintaining contacts can be problematic.
2. Use [this addon](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=17911%2015419333077600929934).  I have never used it and can offer no advice either way.  I believe your domain Admin will need to set it up and I do not think it populates a spreadsheet, so you won't be able to embed your contacts.
3. Write a custom Google Apps Script.  The benefit here is you could use a script to also display the contacts in a clean fashion, with the name as a link, or otherwise.  The downside here is you need to write a script.  It is javascript based so if you have someone who can do that, it may be your best option.  I have done this for a staff directory, which lists all of our domain accounts:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am considering option 3. I have written this so far:       function myContact() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("test").getContacts();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail());
}       This code has been able to find the user from the group test. The test group is under my contacts. However, I need to access the user from "Other Contacts" or "Directory. " These aren't under my contacts. They are on their own. Please help

Comment: I would suggest starting a new post with that question.  Others will be better able/more apt to respond that way.  I have never written anything to read the user's contacts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did just that